# How to link to the portal home page in a skin?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

We have our own custom DotNetNuke 7 skin based on Bootstrap 3. It includes a `navbar` in which I want to have a `navbar-brand` that links to the home page.

**Is it possible to generate a link to the portal home page inside a skin?**

On the [documentation page](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/skins) I found a link to the [Skin Objects Guide (pdf)](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/portals/0/coreteam/blogfiles/timobreumelhof/dotnetnuke%205%20skin%20objects%20beta%20doc%204.pdf) suggesting `[Portal:url]`, which I tried like this:

```
<a href="[Portal:url]" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
```

Not surprisingly this doesn't work (the pdf is from 2009). The other links from the wiki are either dead or useless.

I've also tried looking through the "Gravity" and "Aphelia" skins that come with DotNetNuke, but nowhere do the ascx files seem to link to the portal home page.

Obviously I've also tried GoogleFu in various forms, e.g. ["DotNetNuke skin create link to home page"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=DotNetNuke%20skin%20create%20link%20to%20home%20page), but this leads nowhere.

Anyone know how to do this? Or much preferred even: where I could've found this- and related info? Or am I doomed to dive into the source code of DNN?

Comment: Did you have a chance to test the solution, or did you choose another way to manage to link to the homepage?

Comment: @samy I hadn't yet, but have now. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's dangerous to go alone. Take this:

```
<a href="<%= DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(PortalController.GetCurrentPortalSettings().HomeTabId) %>" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
```

`NavigateUrl` is your goto method to handle referencing another part of your portal. It goes through url rewriting so it will be consistent with the rest of your urls.

There a plenty of signature overloads for this function, where you can specify keys, controlkey, settings, etc. Have a look at the `DotNetNuke.Common.Globals` class for more info.

Note that if you use the abovementioned version, you'll need to have a "Home" page set for your portal under admin > site settings.

Comment: You're probably right, the `NavigateURL` method does seem to be a good companion for this dangerous trip. The exact version from the answer did not work in my quick test (it gave me the TabId for the *current* page in URLs), but I'm thinking it may be because of my specific set up. I will further test your solution and get back here to let yall know how the final solution turned out.

Comment: If you need to resolve the TabId for a page by its name, first go through the `GetTabByName` from the `DotnetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController` class, this will get you the correct TabId.

Comment: Got around to trying your solution. For some reason I had no "Home" page for my portal (mistakingly assumed that this would not be possible). After setting a home page mentioned solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

In DNN 7 it would be best to do this:

```
<%=DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(PortalController.Instance.GetCurrentPortalSettings().HomeTabId) %>
```

Note the extra `Instance.` in there. The variant `PortalController.GetCurrentPortalSettings()` is obsolete.

Comment: Heya, thanks for your answer. Looking at the DNN codebase I can imagine that the variant without `Instance` is obsolete, but it isn't quite attributed as such (is it?). Do you have any link to source code or documentation that explains why the other variant is obsolete?